# run $.ajax() when end typed with format specified. how is it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-effects, typeof

i want, when user typed, 0000/00/00(it is format date) after the end of typing run anything(example: AJAX CALL), how is it?

```
like:
if user typed: 2011/05/04 -> run: $.ajax()...
if user typed: 2011/05 -> not run: $.ajax()...
...
```

only thing for run $.ajax() is true type this format 0000/00/00.
I hope you understand my purpose.
With respect.

Comment: After he types it where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="datefield" onchange="validateField(this)" />
```

JS:

```
function validateField() {
   var val = this.value;
   if (val.length < 10) {
      return;
   }
   if (!val.match(/\d\d\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d/)) {
      return;
   }
   ... do ajax call here
}
```

Comment: You have to be careful cause this will match "blah blah 2011/02/04" as well. You would need to do /^\d\d\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d$/ if the only thing allowed in there is the date.

Comment: True enough, just a quick/dirty example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("inputTextBoxSelector").keyup(function(e){
  if($(this).val().match(/\d\d\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d/){
    $.ajax(....);
    return false;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do...

```
$('input').change(function(e) {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if ( val.length == 10 ) {
    if( val.match(/^\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) ) {
      $.ajax();
    }
  }
});
```

You can also try keyup instead of change.